# trying to delete hidden names by selection excel macro

Tags: excel, named-ranges, vba

I'm trying to delete hidden `Names` but with a rule that I choose what hidden `Name` to delete and what not.

Using the code from Microsoft support I managed to make a list of the names
on a log sheet and added a column that when I enter `1` next to it I want to not delete the name, and when I leave it blank U want it to remove the name.

- code from Microsoft support (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/119826/macro-to-remove-hidden-names-in-active-workbook)

here is my code:

```
Sub clean_names()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next

Set nms = ActiveWorkbook.Names
MsgBox (nms.Count)

For R = 1 To nms.Count
    Name_Name = nms(R).Name
    Name_Referance = nms(R).RefersTo
    '###########ActiveWorkbook.Names(Name_Name).Delete
    'ActiveWorkbook.nms(R).Delete
    Sheets("LOG").Cells(R + 1, 1).Value = Name_Name
    Sheets("LOG").Cells(R + 1, 2).Value = "'" + Name_Referance
    'Application.StatusBar = R
Next R
'Application.StatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

'================================================================

Sub DelNames()

Dim xName As Variant
Dim Indx As Integer
Dim Vis As Variant

Cells(2, 1).Select
If (ActiveCell = "") Then Exit Sub
Indx = 1

Do
    If (ActiveCell.Offset(Indx, 2) = "") Then

        xName = ActiveCell.Offset(Indx, 0).Value
        If xName.Visible = True Then
            Vis = "Visible"
        Else
            Vis = "Hidden"
        End If
        xName.Delete
    End If
    Indx = Indx + 1
Loop While Len(ActiveCell.Offset(Indx, 0))

End Sub
```

How can i make this code work ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, it will loop thorugh all rows in Column A, check if column C is empty, and will delete that `Name` from your workbook.

*Note*: I've commented 5 lines from your original code, since according to your post you don't care if the `Names` are `Visible` or not, you want to delete them based on the value in Column C.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub DelNames()

Dim xName           As Name
Dim Indx            As Long
Dim Vis             As Variant
Dim LastRow         As Long

With Worksheets("LOG")
    If IsEmpty(.Range("A2").Value) Then Exit Sub

    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '<-- get last row in column A (where you have a NamedRange)
    For Indx = 2 To LastRow
        If .Range("C" & Indx).Value = "" Then
            ' set xName with the text entered in column A (as the Named Range Name)
            Set xName = ThisWorkbook.Names(.Range("A" & Indx).Value)

            ' not sure you need the 5 lines with the If criteria below so I Commented them for now
            'If xName.Visible = True Then
            '    Vis = "Visible"
            'Else
            '    Vis = "Hidden"
            'End If
            xName.Delete
        End If
    Next Indx
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @Tal Kuce have you tried my code above ? if it's working for you mark as "ANSWER" , this is how we do thing here on SO. People ask questions, and once they get answers, they credit by marking as "ANSWER"